# Alternative Boolean class to motivate that scala is fully object oriented

Tags: scala, boolean

In the coursera course*, Martin Odersky argues that scala is fully object oriented and shows that Boolean could be defined as a class from first principles (instead of using the primitive Boolean of the JVM).

He defines the alternative boolean class as follows:

```
package week4

abstract class Boolean2 {

  def ifThenElse[T](t: => T, e: => T): T

  def && (x: => Boolean2): Boolean2 = ifThenElse(x, False) 
  def || (x: => Boolean2): Boolean2 = ifThenElse(True, x) 
  def unary_! : Boolean2 = ifThenElse(False, True)

  def == (x: Boolean2): Boolean2 = ifThenElse(x, x.unary_!) 
  def != (x: Boolean2): Boolean2 = ifThenElse(x.unary_!, x)

  def < (x: Boolean2): Boolean2 = ifThenElse(False, x)
}

object True extends Boolean2 {
  def ifThenElse[T](t: => T, e: => T) = t
}
object False extends Boolean2 {
  def ifThenElse[T](t: => T, e: => T) = e
}
```

I was wondering why does he sometimes use type "T" and sometimes type "Boolean2" depending on the method ("T" for "ifThenElse" and "Boolean2" for all other methods like "&&", ...). Furthermore why does he sometimes use the default "call by value" implementation and sometimes the "call by name" ("=>") implementation? I know the difference between both but why is it useful here?

Thanks in advance for the time and help

*Functional Programming Principles in Scala (week 4, Lecture 4.1 Objects Everywhere)

Code copy/pasted from [here](https://github.com/xiaoyunyang/coursera-scala-specialization/blob/master/coursera-functional/src/week4/Boolean2.scala)

Comment: Some hints: What does `if (true) 1 else 2` return in Scala? Does it return a `Boolean` or an `Int`? What, then, should `Boolean2.ifThenElse` return? A `Boolean2` or something else? And what?

Comment: Hint #2: What does `if (true) println("True") else println("False")` print in Scala? Does it print `True` or does it print *both* `True` *and* `False`? When are normal method arguments evaluated? Is Scala lazy or eager, strict or non-strict?

Comment: Hint #B.1: Is `list.head` [evaluated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for empty lists in `list.isEmpty || list.head == 0`?

Comment: Is it really appropriate to put hints in comments like this? Why not simply answer the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is the return type of the then-block and the else-block in the `ifThenElse` function, this can be an arbitrary type but has to match for both blocks.

The call-by-name is used to execute only the block of `ifThenElse` that is going to be returned depending on the condition. 
If you would use call-by-value, both blocks would be evaluated before the `ifThenElse` function is called. This is not only a performance optimisation, but with exceptions or not-terminating calculations it would also change the semantic of `ifThenElse` compared to the build in `if ... then ... else`

Comment: Thanks, good explanation. Does it mean that for the "<" method, we should also use call by name for the "x" parameter?

Comment: @user3577165 The comparison operators should always evaluate both expressions before doing the comparison, even if the result is known after evaluating only one of them. They are not `short-cut` operators like `||` and `&&`.